# Combinations of several dicts python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have 15 dicts like the following 3 (all 15 are of varying lengths).
For example:

```
 HQDict = {'HQ1':10, 'HQ2':3, 'HQ3':5}
 BADict = {'BA1':15, 'BA2':4, 'BA3':3}
 STDict = {'ST1':5, 'ST2':4, 'ST3':3}
```

I want to create all the possible combinations of the 15 dicts with only one element selected from each dict with the values added together and the keys stored in a list. I have been able to get all the information into the respective dicts but I am clueless on where to start with the combinations, I have seen itertools.combinations but I'm not sure how to make it only select 1 element from each dict. If you need any more information please ask and I will be happy to edit.

Edit1:
I also needed to add that the values are additive so value of BA2 will be the value of BA1 + BA2 and that the combination could be a list of 1.

```
list=[HQ1,BA2,ST1]
value=34

next permutation
list=[HQ2]
value=13
```

Edit2:

Rather than try and create the combinations of the dicts the end goal is to give the function a total and it will return all the possible combinations of buildings (each dict represents a building and each item in the dict a level) that add up to that total. So for example:

```
combinations(34) would return
[HQ1,BA2,ST1]
and combinations(13 would return
[HQ2]
```

pastebin to file containing all buildings and code im using to create the dicts : [link to pastebin](http://pastebin.com/jSUdS2Vu)

Comment: This looks a lot like a [knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem)

Comment: Thanks for the link when I started looking around the knapsack problem I then found the subset sum problem and this looked more what I was after as the knapsack problem was looking for optimal solutions however I was after exact solutions. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem

Answer (score 4):

> I have seen itertools.combinations but I'm not sure how to make it only select 1 element from each dict.

Use `itertools.product(..)` instead. It takes a varying list of arguments each corresponding to a list of options to pick in one iteration:

```
>>> map(dict, product(HQDict.items(), STDict.items(), BADict.items()))
[{'HQ1': 10, 'BA2': 4, 'ST1': 5}, {'HQ1': 10, 'ST1': 5, 'BA3': 3}, ...... ]
```

If you have 15 such dicts, I'd suggest putting all of them in a list, and calling product like below:

```
>>> map(dict, product(*list_of_dicts))
```

**EDIT**: In python3, you will get a map object back, and you'll have to iterate over it to get the actual values. You can convert it to a list, but will defeat the purpose of map returning something that you can iterate over. You can convert to a list like:

```
>>> [dict(x) for x in product(HQDict.items(), STDict.items(), BADict.items())]
[{'HQ1': 10, 'BA2': 4, 'ST1': 5}, {'HQ1': 10, 'ST1': 5, 'BA1': 15}, ..]
```

Comment: I don't. As you see in the output above. Can you put up a Minimum verifiable complete example ?

Comment: Are you using python3 or python 2?

Comment: I was using python2, in python3 you will get a `map` object in return. I'll update my answer..

Comment: Ok I'm also using python 2. I've thought of a different approach to look at the problem I will edit my answer trying to outline what I am trying and why I wanted to try combinations.